# VSCode add already existig code snippets from another folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have a very large project with hundreds of files and complex folders structure. Code snippets that are convenient for me have been created there.

Sometimes I like to change the scope to a specific nested subdirectory (Open this folder in another VSCode instance). In such a situation, already created snippets do not work.

Can I configure VSCode to use snippets from an existing file in another directory?

Comment: copy the needed snippet files to the global snippet directory